# Context sensitive cross reference using Cleveref and Varioref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

I am blocked to make a command (called `\pref{<cross-reference>}`) for cross-references using `cleveref` and `varioref`. I would like it to be able to adapt to the context :

- First, I would like to be able to remove the comma when the reference is on the same page as the referenced object. This is what I currently have :
  [image]
- Secondly, I would have liked to know if it was possible to add the name of the chapter or section to which reference is made without calling on `\crefformat` and thus be able to use the command `\cref` with its default behavior in other contexts.

Here's what I currently have:
[image]

Here's what I'd like to be able to post:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref, hyperref, cleveref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\def\reftextcurrent{}
\def\reftextfaraway#1{p.~\pageref{#1}}
\crefformat{figure}{#2\textsc{Fig.}~#1#3}
\crefformat{section}{#2\textsc{Sec.}~#1#3}

\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\cref{#1}, \vpageref{#1})}

\begin{document}
\pref{fig1}\qquad\pref{sec1}

\clearpage
\pref{fig1}\qquad\pref{sec1}\\
(\cref{sec1} : \textit{\nameref{sec1}}, \vpageref{sec1})% desired behaviour

\clearpage
\section{My section}\label{sec1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering\Huge Figure
    \caption{Bla bla.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\pref{fig1}\qquad\pref{sec1}\\
(\cref{fig1})\qquad(\cref{sec1} : \textit{\nameref{sec1}})% desired behaviour

\clearpage
\pref{fig1}\qquad\pref{sec1}

\clearpage
\pref{fig1}\qquad\pref{sec1}
\end{document}
```